# how ssh-agent process is increasing on every login

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

i have added the following line in my .bashrc file to start ssh-agent if it is not running.

```
if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ];then eval `ssh-agent -s`;ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_private_key;fi
```

But every time when i login again the number of ssh-agent process is increasing How to avoid this. please see the following logs and tell what i did wrong.

```
[vm@localhost ~]$ ssh root@192.168.x.x
Last login: Wed Feb 15 06:32:07 2017 from x.x.x.x
[root@server ~]#  pgrep ssh-agent | wc -l
2
[root@server ~]# exit
Shared connection to x.x.x.x closed.

[vm@localhost ~]$ ssh root@192.168.x.x
Last login: Wed Feb 15 06:32:20 2017 from x.x.x.x
[root@server ~]#  pgrep ssh-agent | wc -l
3
[root@server ~]# exit
Shared connection to x.x.x.x closed.

[vm@localhost ~]$ ssh root@192.168.x.x
Last login: Wed Feb 15 06:32:25 2017 from x.x.x.x
[root@server ~]#  pgrep ssh-agent | wc -l
4
```

Comment: You probably want to stop the agent, when you log out.

Comment: yes and also just want to ensure that only one process of ssh-agent will run.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, are you doing this over an ssh session? If so, then you can use `ssh -A user@host.com` and don't even use ssh-agent. The `-A` option will forward your host's ssh-agent to the remote server. Then you don't even need to copy your ssh keys to the remote server.

Back to the original question: The problem with running `ssh-agent` is that by default it will use a different random socket name every time. That's why your ssh-agent processes keep increasing. What you want to do is use the `ssh-agent -a` option to provide a fixed socket. Then no matter how many times you call it, it won't start another ssh-agent.

Here's a simple script that will always re-use the same ssh-agent, or start ssh-agent if it isn't running. You can easily combine these 3 lines into a 1 line alias as well.

```sh
# set SSH_AUTH_SOCK env var to a fixed value
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~/.ssh/ssh-agent.sock

# test whether $SSH_AUTH_SOCK is valid
ssh-add -l 2>/dev/null >/dev/null

# if not valid, then start ssh-agent using $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
[ $? -ge 2 ] && ssh-agent -a "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" >/dev/null
```

[source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132065/how-do-i-get-ssh-agent-to-work-in-all-terminals/132117#132117)

Comment: *Both* agent forwarding and storing a personal key on a remote host are most often the wrong solution. Making a key available to a remote machine that does not technically need that access is just an unnecessary attack vector.